# Перегрузка или не перегрузка? Вот в чем вопрос: Java

Tags: java, ооп

Однажды, во время обсуждений, у меня возник философский вопрос, который мучает меня до сих пор: А является ли перегрузкой "перегрузка" метода в классе наследнике в Java?

Те, если класс родитель имеет метод:

```
String get(int a)
```

А класс наследник:

```
String get(int a, int b)
```

Перегрузка ли это?

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае имеет место типичная перегрузка, т.к.:

- Методы имеют разные сигнатуры (отличаются параметры);
- Метод наследника не переопределяет метод родителя.

Comment: Но, ведь, методы принадлежат разным классам, и, имеют разное описание (имеется ввиду, класс+метод). Скажем, при "переопределении" static методов в классе наследнике - это не является переопределение (статика относится к классу), тут же тоже замешано 2 класса. Разве, перегрузка это не "фича" в рамках одного класса?

Comment: @Valery наследник имеет тот же метод что и предок "по опредлению". значит можно считать что все происходит в рамках одного класса в любом случае:)